# React Native map crashes only with apk

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am developing a react native app with several screens. It has a screen that loads react native map. It's working perfectly on debug when I run `react-native run-android`. But when I create the signed apk and install it on a device other screens work fine, but when I navigate to the screen with map, the app crashes. This happened only with apk. So, I can't find a reason as well. This is how I implemented map.

**/app/build.gradle/**

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
implementation project(':@react-native-community_geolocation')
implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){        
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'        
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'    
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.campaign">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="API KEY"/>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

**Code**

```
<MapView style={[styles.mapStyle, { flex: 1, width: this.state.mapWidth }]}
          initialRegion={{
                 latitude: this.state.latitude,
                 longitude: this.state.longitude,
                 latitudeDelta: 0.1,
                 longitudeDelta: 0.1,
              }}
              provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
              onPress={this.onMapPress.bind(this)}
              showsUserLocation={true}
              followsUserLocation={true}
              showsMyLocationButton={true}
              showsCompass={true}
              showsTraffic={true}
              toolbarEnabled={true}
              onMapReady={() => this.setState({ width: width - 1 })}
        >
        <Marker draggable
              coordinate={{
                  latitude: this.state.latitude,
                  longitude: this.state.longitude,
               }}
               onDragEnd={(e) => this.setState({ x: e.nativeEvent.coordinate })}
        />
        <Circle
            center={{
                  latitude: this.state.latitude,
                  longitude: this.state.longitude,
               }}
            radius={this.state.radius}
            fillColor='rgba(253, 48, 4,0.5)'
            strokeColor='rgba(253, 48, 4,1)'
        />
```

**Crash report from android studio**

> 2020-01-23 12:01:07.449 542-542/? E/ThermalBinder: mThermalService is NULL!
>   2020-01-23 12:01:07.449 542-542/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [battery] temp :34  report_threshold:1
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.123 413-490/? E/PF_IPA: [configValues:218] open file [/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/mode] failed! 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.454 1873-1873/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.457 1873-1873/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.485 1873-2988/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.490 1873-16600/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.491 1873-2988/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.502 1873-16600/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.510 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: isSecondaryUser() start 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.510 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: isSecondaryUser() end 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.510 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: removeCallbacksAndMessages start 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.510 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: removeCallbacksAndMessages end 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.510 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: startService end 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.518 1873-16376/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.522 1873-16376/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.522 1873-2667/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.528 1873-2667/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.548 1873-7253/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.550 1873-7253/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.570 1873-2669/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.572 1873-2669/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.583 1873-2113/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.586 1873-2113/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.589 1873-2103/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.591 1873-2103/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.595 1873-2987/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.598 1873-2987/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.599 1478-1778/? E/HwSystemManager: LeisureTrafficSetting:result is empty
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.649 1478-1778/? E/HwSystemManager: CommonMethodUtil:No package name to uid:-5
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.657 1478-1778/? E/HwSystemManager: CommonMethodUtil:No package name to uid:-4
>   2020-01-23 12:01:12.677 1478-1778/? E/HwSystemManager: NotificationUtil:Month Warning Notification not create
>   2020-01-23 12:01:13.123 413-490/? E/PF_IPA: [resetValues:163] open file [/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/mode] failed! 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:13.502 413-490/? E/PF_IPA: [configValues:218] open file [/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/mode] failed! 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.444 1873-1873/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.447 1873-1873/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.473 1873-16600/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.476 1873-2103/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.476 1873-16600/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.478 1873-2103/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.498 1873-16600/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.503 413-490/? E/PF_IPA: [resetValues:163] open file [/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/mode] failed! 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.509 1873-16600/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.516 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: isSecondaryUser() start 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.516 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: isSecondaryUser() end 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.516 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: removeCallbacksAndMessages start 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.516 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: removeCallbacksAndMessages end 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.516 2986-2986/? E/Mms_TXM_SVC: startService end 
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.529 1873-2670/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.532 1873-2670/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.544 1873-1886/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.547 1873-1886/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.558 1873-1886/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.560 1873-1886/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.571 1873-16600/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.574 1873-16600/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.578 1873-2989/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.581 1873-2989/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.583 1478-1778/? E/HwSystemManager: LeisureTrafficSetting:result is empty
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.596 1873-16376/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.600 1873-16376/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.634 1478-1778/? E/HwSystemManager: CommonMethodUtil:No package name to uid:-5
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.644 1478-1778/? E/HwSystemManager: CommonMethodUtil:No package name to uid:-4
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.672 1478-1778/? E/HwSystemManager: NotificationUtil:Month Warning Notification not create
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.870 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GpsOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=1, svId=4, toe=TOC/1263751200.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.870 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GpsOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=1, svId=4, toe=TOC/1263751200.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:14.876 28742-28742/? E/Lss: GNSS or predictor state for GPS SV 3 is bad, prediction not done
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.082 2221-2312/? E/LogCollectService: illegal eventid
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.083 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GpsOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=1, svId=32, toe=TOC/1263751200.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.083 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GpsOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=1, svId=32, toe=TOC/1263751200.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.089 28742-28742/? E/Lss: GNSS or predictor state for GPS SV 31 is bad, prediction not done
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.230 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GlonassOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=2, svId=9, toe=TOC, gps_secs=1263748518.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.230 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GlonassOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=2, svId=9, toe=TOC, gps_secs=1263748518.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.235 28742-28742/? E/Lss: GNSS or predictor state for SV 8 is bad, prediction not done
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.256 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GlonassOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=2, svId=12, toe=TOC, gps_secs=1263748518.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.256 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GlonassOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=2, svId=12, toe=TOC, gps_secs=1263748518.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.261 28742-28742/? E/Lss: GNSS or predictor state for SV 11 is bad, prediction not done
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.369 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GlonassOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=2, svId=19, toe=TOC, gps_secs=1263748518.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.369 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] GlonassOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=2, svId=19, toe=TOC, gps_secs=1263748518.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.374 28742-28742/? E/Lss: GNSS or predictor state for SV 18 is bad, prediction not done
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.448 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] BeidouOrbitPredictor: initialize: Rejects an ephemeris because SVID number 28 is invalid.
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.448 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] BeidouOrbitPredictor: initialize: Rejects an ephemeris because SVID number 28 is invalid.
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.453 28742-28742/? E/Lss: GNSS or predictor state for Beidou SV 27 is bad, prediction not done
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.457 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] BeidouOrbitPredictor: initialize: Rejects an ephemeris because SVID number 19 is invalid.
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.457 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] BeidouOrbitPredictor: initialize: Rejects an ephemeris because SVID number 19 is invalid.
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.462 28742-28742/? E/Lss: GNSS or predictor state for Beidou SV 18 is bad, prediction not done
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.465 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] BeidouOrbitPredictor: initialize: Rejects an ephemeris because SVID number 16 is invalid.
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.465 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] BeidouOrbitPredictor: initialize: Rejects an ephemeris because SVID number 16 is invalid.
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.471 28742-28742/? E/Lss: GNSS or predictor state for Beidou SV 15 is bad, prediction not done
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.631 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] BeidouOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=3, svId=2, toe=TOC/1263747614.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.631 28742-28742/? E/[EELIB] BeidouOrbitPredictor: initialize: prediction disabled for gnss=3, svId=2, toe=TOC/1263747614.000000
>   2020-01-23 12:01:15.636 28742-28742/? E/Lss: GNSS or predictor state for Beidou SV 1 is bad, prediction not done
>   2020-01-23 12:01:16.757 1873-1873/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:16.764 1873-1873/? E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   2020-01-23 12:01:17.455 542-542/? E/Thermal-daemon: [battery] temp_new :33  temp_old :34
>   2020-01-23 12:01:17.456 542-542/? E/ThermalBinder: mThermalService is NULL!
>   2020-01-23 12:01:17.456 542-542/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [battery] temp :33  report_threshold:1
>   2020-01-23 12:01:17.458 542-542/? E/Thermal-daemon: [ap] temp_new :40  temp_old :39
>   2020-01-23 12:01:17.459 542-542/? E/ThermalBinder: mThermalService is NULL!
>   2020-01-23 12:01:17.459 542-542/? E/Thermal-daemon: Report temperature: [ap] temp :40  report_threshold:1

Am I doing anything wrong? What should I do to make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share log of the crash message in logcat in the android studio when you try to navigate to map view page in case if you don't know to  get  the crash message so open android  studio then you see logcat in bottom click on that and there is four dropdowns go to third one chose error and connect your app with sign app navigate to map page see what error message is coming on crash and share that

Comment: Hi, I updated the question following your feedback. Could you please analyze it.

Comment: Can you try to replace:
```if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
}```
with 
```implementation jscFlavor```
and make a new build ? If that works, it is a problem with hermes

Comment: No sir, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add this code block to android/build.gradle and check your versions

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0" // or set latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
}
```

You must add this code block into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
  ...
  <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this issue in 2022, do ensure to:

1. Add the latest Google play services version in your app/build.gradle. You can find the latest playServicesVersion by checking:[here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) and searching for `gms:play-services-maps:`. For me, i had to do this:

```
dependecies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'        
    ...
}
```

2. Add your Google Maps API key to your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file under the `<application />` block. E.G:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your-API-key-goes-here"/>
    ...
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Clean and rebuild your project, and try on a device.